# Make all the first letters uppercase except for words with at max 3 characters

Tags: c#, text, uppercase

I have a text file that the users can edit with many strings, I would like to have all the first letters uppercase except for words with <= 3 characters that must be all uppercase.

using LINQPAD I read the txt file like this 
`var textFile = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\...\...\...\...\uppercase.txt");`

**example of a file** :
THE PEN IS ON THE TABLE
The cat is UNder ThE Table
The ChiLDreN Are ON The trampoline

**Wanted output:**
THE PEN IS ON THE Table
THE CAT IS Under THE Table
THE Children ARE ON THE Trampoline

Comment: What did you try? Where are you stuck? [ask]

Comment: `if (word.Length <= 3) { return word.ToUpper(); } else { return char.ToUpper(word[0]) + word.Substring(1).ToLower(); }`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this approach:

```
var newWords = textFile.Split(' ')
    .Select(w => w.Length <= 3 ? w.ToUpper() : char.ToUpper(w[0]) + w[1..].ToLower());
textFile = String.Join(" ", newWords);
```

Answer (score 2):

Given `text`:

```
string text = 
   @"THE PEN IS ON THE TABLE
     The cat is UNder ThE Table
     The ChiLDreN Are ON The trampoline";
```

We can use regular expressions to do replacements:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Globalization;

...

string result = Regex.Replace(text,
  @"\p{L}+",
    match => match.Value.Length > 3
      ? CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(match.Value)
      : match.Value.ToUpper());
```

Here I treat `word` as a non empty sequence of letters `\p{L}+`. Please, note, that regular expressions unlike split *respect punctuations*:

```
"The cat! Not a dog" -> "THE CAT! NOT A DOG"
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dJAaBE)

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I did it:

```cs
string txt = "THE PEN IS ON THE TABLE\nThe cat is UNder ThE Table\nThe ChiLDreN Are ON The trampoline";
var lines = txt.Split('\n');
```

I split `txt` with `\n` first, then:

```cs
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    var words = line.Split(' ');
    foreach (var word in words)
    {
        if (word.Length <= 3)
        {
            Console.Write(word.ToUpper() + " ");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write(word.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + word.Substring(1).ToLower() + " ");
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Then I used a foreach loop to iterate through the `lines` array to get each element in it and split it with `Split(' ')`.

Then I used another foreach loop to iterate through each element in `words` to get each word in it and do the capitalization and printing.

I am new to C# and just wanted to help since I tried this approach and it worked.